# How to close/finish call ended screen in android program

Tags: android, android-intent

I built an app to auto redial phone number. After users hang up the phone call, I need to prompt show my activity for user to handle some cases.
What problem I met is, when I dial a phone number in Samsung S3, then hang up the phone call.
A call ended screen will stay 3-5 seconds(it's longer than other mobile phone), then go back to my activity of APP automatically.
3-5 seconds is too long for me, so are there any way to force close/finish the call ended screen?

Comment: This seems to be a question about how to use Android, and it would be better off asked at http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. You cannot change the behavior of other apps from within your apps, if those apps don't support such workarounds. You will have to live with that.

Moreover, even if you are able to fix it for 1 model, you cannot do it for all the other models. So, I would suggest, try thinking of another solution.